# MySQL: Query with SUM(if ..)

Tags: mysql, sql

Please, help me with query:

```
SELECT 
    N.site_name, 
    Count(N.site_name), 
    SUM (IF((SC.type_conn = 'GET') && (SC.type_conn = 'CONNECT'),N.size_site,0)) as Traffic_IN, 
    SUM (IF(SC.type_conn = 'POST',N.size_site,0)) as Traffic_OUT 
From 
    news N, 
    status_conn SC, 
    users U 
where 
    N.id_conn = SC.id_conn and 
    N.id_user = U.id_user and 
    U.name_user = 'max' and 
    N.date_conn = '2015-08-04' 
Group by 
    N.site_name 
Order by 
    SUM (IF((SC.type_conn = 'GET') && (SC.type_conn = 'CONNECT'),N.size_site,0))
```

Comment: Please don't use this type of `JOIN`s, And clarify us about how can we help you?! ;).

Comment: What kind of help do you need ? Any specific error ?

Comment: function SUM don`t work, maybe  i have  mistake in query??

Comment: But what is your error message ?

Comment: ERROR : #1630 FUNCTION [name_db].sum does not exist. Check the ' Function Name Parsing and Resolution' action in the Reference Manual

Comment: Oh, simply remove the space between SUM and the first parenthesis, this will allow MySQL to consider it as a function name and not an identifier.

Comment: It is necessary to remove the space before SUM

Comment: You mean "after" SUM :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know witch is the problem; in any case you could try this:

```
Select N.site_name, 
Count(N.site_name), 
SUM (IF((SC.type_conn = 'GET') && (SC.type_conn = 'CONNECT'),N.size_site,0)) as Traffic_IN, 
SUM (IF(SC.type_conn = 'POST',N.size_site,0)) as Traffic_OUT 
From news N, status_conn SC, users U
where N.id_conn = SC.id_conn 
and N.id_user = U.id_user 
and U.name_user = 'max' 
and N.date_conn = '2015-08-04' 
Group by N.site_name 
Order by Traffic_IN
```

otherwise

```
select ...
...
Order by 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may very well have a parenthesis problem at the end of your query. Try

```
[...] ORDER BY SUM (IF((SC.type_conn = 'GET') && (SC.type_conn = 'CONNECT')),N.size_site,0)
```